Pass OTEL context through vertx eventbus in Quarkus
In order for usefull tracing in this application, I need to solve the following challenge.
The app is Quarkus based with the OTEL extension enabled. The proces get started through a POST api, which adds a message to the vertx eventbus. The eventbus triggers async processing of the messages.
I would like to use the context of the API endpoint traces / spans within the async process. To follow the outcome of the post request up until the process is completed. How to solve?
The pseudocode:
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @Inject
    EventBus bus;

    @Inject
    ProcessingService processingService;

    @GET
    @NonBlocking
    public String start() {
        bus.send("topic", "dummyBody");
        return "Hello from Quarkus REST";
    }

    @Blocking
    @ConsumeEvent("topic")
    public void processing(String body) {
        processingService.start();
    }
}

